# Consistent renaming of fields in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, refactoring

When refactoring a field, the default behaviour in eclipse is to rename just the field, leaving accessor methods with inconsistent names.

Pressing `Alt+Shift+R` twice shows a "Renaming dialog" where I can select if accessors should be renamed as well (as two separate options). This eases the pain of manually renaming the accessors, but is still quite suboptimal, involving pressing 3 more shortcuts than with the in-place renaming, plus my usual forgetfulness... :)

I cannot think of a reason why I would NOT like my refactoring to be consistent, so is there a way to make accessor renaming the default behaviour? I'm OK with tweaking cryptic settings and setting obscure flags as long as it works.

Thank you

Comment: I don't think IDE should be able to decide the accessor methods, for instance `getName();` could be a business method instead of simple accessor method

Comment: I remembered that Eclipse seems remember your previous decision: if you have chosen option to rename getter/setter, next time, simply Alt-Shift-R once and getter/setter will be renamed too.  I am not sure which version have such feature though, I know I saw this behavior in 3.5 or 3.6 era

Comment: @JigarJoshi having a field `name` and a method `getName()` doing things unrelated to returning the `name` field is a rather bad design decision IMO. Besides, eclipse already has the mentioned option and I would simply like to make it more accessible

Comment: @AdrianShum you're partially right about eclipse's memory - A single `Alt+Shift+R` still performs a "naive" renaming regardless of prevoius choices. But the setter/getter options remain checked the next time when pressing `Alt+Shift+R` twice. So the overhead is reduced to just one shortcut :) Thanks for noticing.

Comment: (+1) for pointing out the double-`Alt+Shift+R` functionality. I never knew it existed, and it looks very handy indeed.

Comment: You actually expects someone modifies Eclipse plugin?

Comment: @lechlikasz I don't see why not :) I guess I am not the only one with the itch. I could also live with just tweaking the settings, in case such settings are accessible someplace.

Comment: no no... I did remember that I saw a SINGLE Alt-Shift-R will perform rename in getter/setter directly.  Coz I still remember the "scene" that I see the name of variable and getter method name dynamically change when I am typing the new name of var.  Maybe I will have a try to see what I did to bring that feature...

Comment: Just tried that in Eclipse Helios.  A single Alt-Shift-R rename, once pressed enter, will change the getter and setter name too (probably needs to have rename getter/setter selected in the Double Alt-Shift-R rename dialog beforehand)

Comment: @AdrianShum I must have done sth wrong yesterday, have tried it again today and it works :) Care to repost as an answer? I guess, this is the best option so far.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just tried that in Eclipse 3.6 Helios (but I remember it works in Eclipse 3.4 and 3.5 and probably even earlier)

A single Alt-Shift-R rename in the editor, once ENTER is pressed, will change the method name of corresponding getter and setter.  The prerequisite is probably you should have once open the Rename Field dialog by pressing Alt-Shift-R twice, and select options in Rename getter and Rename setter.  Subsequent rename actions will remember your choice on this.